# Create Django dropdown form which allows users to select a model to submit

Tags: django, forms

Extreme noob here. I have been trying to create a simple form in Django where the user can select from the models that are present in the database and then click submit (whereupon I will then return a list of objects).

However, I am getting the following error: **'ModelBase' object is not iterable**
Note all I am trying to achieve so far is to actually render the form.

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<form action="." method="">
  {% csrf_token %}
{% for field in output %}

    {{ output.as_p }}

{% endfor %}
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

**Forms.py**

```
from projectdb.models import *

class TablesForm(forms.Form):
    models = models.get_models()
    select = forms.ChoiceField(choices=models)
```

**Views.py**

```
def output_form(request):
    form = TablesForm()
    return render(request, 'projectdb/output.html', {'output': form})
```

Much obliged for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some **object is not iterable** errors will be fixed by adding .all() where you're doing the foreach loop. If the loop is in the template, try .all only

In a view:

```
for something in array.all():
```

In a template:

```
{% for field in output.all %}
```

And everytime I do a form in Django my method on the form is empty **method=""**. This let's you return to the same view and process your data there. If you have errors on the form you can redirect to the same form but with the pre-saved data that the user has wrote.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks! Your comments were useful. I have fixed the object not iterable bug but the form is still not rendering. All I have is a submit button. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: try this on your view: `return render(request, 'projectdb/output.html', 'extra_context':extra_context)` _Assuming that extra_context is your form..._ And, in your template, use `{% for field in extra_context %}`

I mean, your template needs to know the form you're using. Also you can print your form like this: `{{ extra_context.as_p }}` or as_table

Comment: Sorry, ive just realised how confusing my code is with references to table instead of form. (It is there because I will eventually have a table, but nevermind). I will edit my code above to make more sense.

Comment: I have also tried your suggestion {'extra_context':extra_context} but it had no effect.

Comment: I think your first field of the model is non-sense. In forms you need to create fields like inputs or textarea. Declare your models outside of the form and try it. Algo try adding a field like `name = models.CharField(max_length=20)` to test if your view and template are working properly.

Comment: I think it is the view/template not working. I have tested using name = forms.CharField(max_length=20) and other fields and none appear. With respect to the form, the field is meant to gather all of the model classes in a drop down. I have looped through the 'form' variable outside of the form and it does print them correctly. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this can help, but try to change the name of your select. Maybe it's getting errors like when you make a `<input type="text" name="name">` in HTML5. Clear your Form and put only the name field for testing.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. This is really strange problem. I don't have any instinct as to what is wrong as I cant even generate a basic form. Very odd. Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: OK, so i got a simple form working again. Just a stupid typo somewhere. So yes, I can verify that my line of code select = forms.ChoiceField(choices=models) is causing the whole form not to render properly.

Comment: After trying the forms.ChoiceField() with a number of different lists it seems just never to render the field. So I think I have narrowed it down to that line being the problem.

Comment: @Sirrah Think I got it, just add a max_length in the ChoiceField like `select = forms.ChoiceField(max_length=30, choices=models)` 

I had that problem in past. You can change the max_length value if you need large content.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your comments. I've figured it out! It is in the documentation and somehow I just missed it when reading through before. 

Of the argument choices it says: An iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) of 2-tuples, consisting itself of iterables of exactly two items (e.g. [(A, B), (A, B) ...]) to use as choices for this field.

Also, the first element in each tuple is the actual value to be stored, and the second element is the human-readable name.

So there you go, I need to pass in my data in that format.

Comment: right, so you need to put models outside the Form and iterate over it for create the list or the tuple. `for model in models: RESULT.append((model, model.name))`. Or something like that...

Comment: Yup, I'm working on something like that now. It is still being particularly finicky but at least we reached the answer (I got it to work with a simple 2-tuple). Should I mark this correct or just leave it?

Comment: Well, that's your decission, I'll apreciatte if you mark as correct even if I didn't found your answer, but I tried a lot and searched info too. I hate when I have problems like that and no one wants to help.